# How to merge DF-s in are with multible conditions?

Tags: r, merge

I have two DF and i want to merge them using link conditions from two different columns. Using "name" and "product_ID" i want to add total from the second DF to the first.

DF "Detail"

```
 
Name   product_ID    Amount
Apple    011           5
Apple    11            10
Apple    011           20
Orange   011           10
Orange   011           5
```

DF General

```
 
Name   product_ID    Total
Apple    011           50
Apple    11            25
Orange   011           20
```

I want: DF detail

```
 
Name   product_ID    Amount     total
Apple    011           5          50
Apple    11            10         25
Apple    011           20         50
Orange   011           10         20
Orange   011           5          20
```

When i would only use 1 condition I would use the merge
Detail <- merge(Detail, General[, C("Name", "total")], "Name", all.X=TRUE)

I dont know how to make it use both "Name" and product_ID.

I was thinking that i could also make a new column where i add "Name" and "product_ID" in to one column but i don't know how to add two factor togeather in to a singe column.

Hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse`-solution for you that uses `join` instead of `merge` but it does do the trick nicely.

Your combination approach is indeed a good idea if you do not want to use the tidyverse. If your df has `factor`s instead of `character`s as in this solution, you could just convert them with `as.character`

The promised solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
  
  general <- read_table('Name   product_ID    Amount
Apple    011           5
Apple    11            10
Apple    011           20
Orange   011           10
Orange   011           5') 
  
  detail <- read_table('Name   product_ID    Total
Apple    011           50
Apple    11            25
Orange   011           20')
  
  df <- general %>% 
    full_join(detail)
#> Joining, by = c("Name", "product_ID")
  
  df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   Name   product_ID Amount Total
#>   <chr>  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Apple  011             5    50
#> 2 Apple  11             10    25
#> 3 Apple  011            20    50
#> 4 Orange 011            10    20
#> 5 Orange 011             5    20
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>